# trying to get table row count value but got Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null

Tags: javascript, php, android, json

i'm new in this thing, so i need help with my current problem, i'm trying to get table row count value but "Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value Result of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject" appear

here's my rowcount.php :

```js
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "smkkimmanuel2");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM pendaftaran")) {

    /* determine number of rows result set */
    $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
 printf("Result set has %d rows.\n", $row_cnt);
 $response["rowcount"] = $row_cnt;
 die(json_encode($response));
}


?>
```

and my row_count_test class :

```js
package id.wanda.smkkkristenimmanuelii;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Row_count_test extends Activity {

 private TextView testRowCount;
 
 // flag for Internet connection status
    Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
     
    // Connection detector class
    ConnectionDetector cd;

 // JSON parser class
 JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

 private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://192.168.1.110/smkkimmanuel2/rowcount.php";


 // JSON element ids from repsonse of php script:
 private static final String TAG_ROWCOUNT = "rowcount";

 public static String row;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_row_count_test);
  
  testRowCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);
  new RowCount().execute();
 }
 public void rowCount(View v) {
  
  
 }

 class RowCount extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

  
  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
   String getRow;
   // getting product details by making HTTP request
   JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequestRowCount(LOGIN_URL);
   try {
     getRow = json.getString(TAG_ROWCOUNT);
     row = getRow;
     
    
   } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }catch (NullPointerException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }

   return row;
  }
  
  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String row) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   testRowCount.setText(row);
  }
 }

 
}
```

here's my JSONObject Mr. @PareshMayani :

```js
public JSONObject makeHttpRequestRowCount(String url, String method) {
 
        // Making HTTP request
        try {
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
 
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
                
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        Log.d("JSON Parser", json);
        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
 
        // return JSON String
        return jObj;
 
    }
```

EDITED :
it seems the problem occurs in the php file, it returning null value.
so i need help with the php file,

here's the new logcat error :

```js
05-26 11:28:46.530: E/Buffer Error(15945): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
05-26 11:28:46.530: E/JSON Parser(15945): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
```

here's the new rowcount.php file :

```js
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "smkkimmanuel2");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM pendaftaran")) {

    /* determine number of rows result set */
    $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
 
 $response["rowcount"] = $row_cnt;
 echo json_encode($response);exit;
}


?>
```

Comment: Remove your debug print statement from `rowcount.php`. Right now you're producing invalid JSON. It's the whole response that matters

Comment: @JeroenSmit i removed the printf("Result set has %d rows.\n", $row_cnt); in rowcount.php, and when i run it, new error occurs, i edit my logcat above, please take a look

Comment: replace code inside if condition( rowcount.php ) as i mention below

Comment: Are you able to get the response from server? If possible then paste the response here!

Comment: @PareshMayani do you mean this {"rowcount":5} Mr. Paresh?

Comment: yup, are you getting that response in android application?

Comment: nope, i don't get that response, my app is crashing everytime i run it, should i post my JSONObject? i'm not quite sure, but it seems the problem is on my JSONObject Sir.

Comment: Mr. @PareshMayani, i updated my post, please take a look Sir, thanks

Comment: That's correct code. What error you are facing now? Please be specific about the issue you are facing. Your question is already been mixed up with unnecessary details!

Comment: Well if i keep my print statement in rowcount.php, this Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value Result of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject error will showing, but if i remove the print statement, the error that showing is like the logcat above the JSONObject in my post Sir

Comment: I have posted an answer with the solutions of both the issues! If there is any error at PHP Side then I can't help you!

Comment: I'll try your solution Sir, i'll post the result later, thank you so much for your help, i really apreciate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've finally solve my problem, first i create a config.php for connection to the database

```js
<?php

 $username = "root";
 $password = "";
 $host = "localhost";
 $dbname = "smkkimmanuel2";

    $options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'); 

    try 
    { 
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    { 
        die("Failed to connect to the database: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    } 
     
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);      
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
     
    if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') && get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
    { 
        function undo_magic_quotes_gpc(&$array) 
        { 
            foreach($array as &$value) 
            { 
                if(is_array($value)) 
                { 
                    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($value); 
                } 
                else 
                { 
                    $value = stripslashes($value); 
                } 
            } 
        } 
     
        undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_POST); 
        undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_GET); 
        undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_COOKIE); 
    } 
     
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 
     
    session_start(); 

?>
```

and tweak my rowcount.php to be like this :

```js
<?php

//load and connect to MySQL database stuff
require("config.php");

    //gets user's info based off of a username.
    $query = "SELECT * FROM pendaftaran_calon_siswa";
    
    
    try {
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        // For testing, you could use a die and message. 
        //die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
        
        //or just use this use this one to product JSON data:
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error1. Please Try Again!";
        die(json_encode($response));
        
    }
    
    //fetching all the rows from the query
 $row = $stmt->fetchAll();
 $rows = count($row);
    
 $response["rowcount"] = $rows;
 echo json_encode($response);
    

?>
```

and it works, don't know how but it works, thanks everyone who's helping me, finally solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Remove printf line and replace as below

```
$row_cnt = $result->num_rows;

// remove this line
//printf("Result set has %d rows.\n", $row_cnt);

$response["rowcount"] = $row_cnt;

//replace this line
//die(json_encode($response));

echo json_encode($response);exit;
```

Comment: the error still occur, i edit my post above, please take a look the logcat.

Comment: have you replaced code inside within if block as i mention above.

Comment: yup, i replaced it, as you mentioned it, but it seems the problem is with my row_count_test class, but i'm not quite sure.

Comment: can you please log response of web service.

Comment: how to do that? i'm sorry, because i'm still newb

Answer (score 1):

You are facing 2 issues:

> 1) 05-25 14:43:42.974: E/JSON Parser(23557): Error parsing data
>   org.json.JSONException: Value Result of type java.lang.String cannot
>   be converted to JSONObject

This exception gets fired when you try to create a JSON object from string and that string is not actually a JSON Object string.

If you are getting `{"rowcount":5}` then that's correct JSON Object.

> 2) java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing
>   doInBackground()
>   Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the > original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

The issue description itself is self-explanatory. Still FYI, this issue is getting raised due to the below line written in `doInBackground()`:

```
testRowCount.setText(row);
```

You can't update any view (i.e. TextView or any other views) while performing background operations. In other way, you can update UI while from main thread only.

To do so, there are 2 ways:

1. Implement `runOnUiThread()` in `doInBackground()` method and write the view updating code inside.
2. Update the UI from `onPostExecute()` method.

Comment: Okay, i'll try that Sir, i'll post the result later, thank you so much Mr. Paresh, that's easy to understand.

Comment: i've tried your solution Mr. Paresh and i'm afraid it's true that the problem is remain in my PHP file, the value returns null in my android app.

anyway, thank you so much for your help Sir, i really appreciate it.
i'll try to figure out this problem.

Comment: Don't actually delete the old details because answers would look different than your actual issue! Rather include the updated details at bottom of the question!

Comment: uh oh okay, i'm sorry it's really my bad Sir, i'm new in this stuff. thanks for telling me how it should be.